# How do I insert the smaller variant of an image?

Tags: admin-menu, images, user-interface

I noticed that when I upload an image in my media library, WordPress seems to automatically generate smaller versions of the image:

[image]

However, I don't know how to access these smaller versions when I want to simply add them as content in a post or page, without just manipulating the `src` attribute manually. I thought that when I set the image size in the attachment settings, this would be done automatically, like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, all this does is set the `width` and `height` attribute of the image, but still access the full size of the image, which is bad for page loading speed, of course.

```
<img src="http://my-website/uploads/2017/10/maehroboter-sicherheit-1024x576.jpg" alt=""
width="640" height="360" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-1952" />
```

This is not what I want.

So how do I access the smaller image versions through the user interface directly? This is especially important, since some of my coworkers are not as technically skilled so that they could just adjust the code for this, so I'm looking for a solution here.

Comment: It should do exactly as you want, because is the correct and WordPress standard behavior. Maybe there's some plugin or theme function interfering with that?